# Problems in win10 tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I have install tensorflow in win10 `C:\Users\lxt\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py3\`.
Now I want to use a tool which build from this command:

> **bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:optimize_for_inference**

My environments are following:

- `bazel version 0.4.5`,
- `libprotoc  version 3.3.0`,
- `python 3.5`,

other tools are in `C:\tools\msys64\usr\bin`,
I first run the ./configure

[image: configure for build]
I met this error:
[image: Error image]
Help me!

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code, errors, or other text. Copy and paste the text into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use screenshots, it's very hard to read and to further process the log.

In the log it said that `sed` invocation failed. That might be because Bazel used some flag that is not supported by your version of `sed`. Maybe you have an old version of msys? What is your `sed` version? Is upgrading an option for you?

You can debug this issue further by running Bazel with the `-s` (or `--subcommands`) flag to see the complete command. Then you can find out which flag was the one that `sed` didn't understand.

You can file an issue on Bazel's github repo if you believe Bazel shouldn't use this flag on Windows.